# How to say "high stakes" more formally?

Tags: phrase-usage

I have in an article a sentence similar to:

> High stakes in surgery call for great care

My supervisor says "high stakes" is too colloquial. Is this really so and if it is, what is a more formal way to say the same?

Comment: "Risky surgery calls for great care."

Comment: Ask him if he would find "With a great deal at stake" too colloquial, as in "With a great deal at stake in surgery, great care is called for."

Comment: @MaxW doesn't that slightly change the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: Yes, it seems that I misunderstood. Maybe something like one of Peter's suggestions below: "The  critical nature of surgery calls for great care."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The risk of serious complications during surgery requires that great care be taken.

Comment: I ended up using  risk of complications (including death). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "High stakes" has become a normalised term but it is still a bit informal. If you want to get more formal you could say "High Pressure" or "High stress" environment and note that there is "little or no room for error".

"With very little room for error in surgery, great care is called for"

Answer (score 0):

For your example, using phrasing like

> The **seriousness** of surgery
>   The **serious nature** of surgery
>   The **patient** *(mission)* **critical nature** of surgery

would have a similar meaning and be more formal

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this when I tried to remember a synonym for 'high-stakes' that I heard used.
It was 'high-leverage', and it's frequently used to describe key situations in sports. For example, in baseball, closers tend to be used in high-leverage situations.
Another one is 'high-impact'.